# Upgrade CentOS 4.4 to 4.8

Tags: centos, yum

I'm new to CentOS, have mainly worked with FreeBSD.

How do i update/upgrade CentOS from version 4.4 to 4.8 ?

**Update**

```
# yum upgrade
```

Will this upgrade only minor or will it upgrade to 5.x ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading from 4.4 to 4.8 is a minor upgrade, and this should be fairly straight forward to do just by using yum, as a matter of fact with the default yum repos that come with your CentOS distribution it should just work out of the box doing `yum upgrade`

Upgrading from 4.4 to 5.x is a bit more of a difficult task though, for the brave souls ;) just make sure to practice it with a box that you don't really need before starting this kind of upgrade on live boxes.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that `yum upgrade` only do minor updates. I have allready started the upgrade, it's a fresh install 4.4 box we have had laying around for a while.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide/ServerCD_4.4_to_5 try above link :)

or if you have 4.8 DVD then following

```
Create a dvd.repo text file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ with the following content:

[dvd]
mediaid=1170972069.396645*
name=DVD for RHEL5
baseurl=file:///media/RHEL_5%20i386%20DVD/Server (For example for RHEL 5.5 version baseurl line should look like 'baseurl=file:///media/RHEL_5.5%20i386%20DVD/Serverenabled=1')
gpgcheck=0

For Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4.8
In /etc/sysconfig/rhn/sources, comment out the following line:
#up2date default

This line needs to be commented out otherwise up2date will keep on looking for information using the Red Hat Network first.

Next, in the same file, create a line like the following:

dir mydvdrepo /media/cdrom/RedHat/RPMS
```

Comment: I do not wish to upgrade to 5.x, i would like it to be exactly 4.8

Comment: Hi Phliplip, i'm not asking to you go with 5.X, what you can do is you use 4.8 DVD copy to your server and create a repo of the same and run up2date !

Comment: Ok, i misunderstood your intentions :) Sorries